# My array is not going up

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a text based adventure game. (This is NOT OOP at all) The problem comes in at my second if statement inside my loop, it is not adding 1 to my array locations[] it keep printing location[0] then a 1 at the end. Not really sure what is going on here.

```
package com.PenguinGaming;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game{


    /*
     * Command list:
     * - investigate (advanced description)
     * - go north
     * - go south
     * - go west
     * - go east
     * - pick up
     * - eat
     * - drink from
     * - drink object
     * - climb up/down
     * - burn
     * - use object
     * - attack
     * - defend
     * - description (basic description)
     * - read
     * - life
     * - help (brings up command list)
     */

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int life = 25;

        boolean running = true;

        String input = null;

        String[] locations = new String[3];
        locations[0] = "Location: Canyon\nDescription: You stand alone over looking a large caynon, \nwater crashing" +
        " into the forsaken pit. A orange cactus stands tall near by. \nTheir is some light brown brush" + 
        " blowing in the wind to the east. \nThe sky is red... Darkness is coming soon.";
        locations[1] = "River";
        locations[2] = "Field";

        //Starting player location
        String player = locations[0];

        //This is how we will navigate the map
        // north + 1, east + 2, south -1, west - 2;
        //player = locations[0] + 1;

        String[] commands = new String[6];
        commands[0] = "investigate";
        commands[1] = "go north";
        commands[2] = "go east";
        commands[3] = "go south";
        commands[4] = "go west";
        commands[5] = "terminate game";

        System.out.println(locations[0]);

        do{
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            input = input.toLowerCase();

            if (input.equals(commands[0])) {
                // give description for location
                System.out.println(player);
            }

            if(input.equals(commands[1])){
                player = player + 1;
                System.out.println(player);
            }
            if(input.equals(commands[5])){
                break;
            }

        }
        while(running == true);
        System.exit(0);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `player = player + 1` is taking the string `player` and adding the string `1` to it. So yeah, it's taking what `player` was before and adding a `1` on the end.

The key here is that `player` is of type `String`. So it's handling `"Location: ...." + 1` as `"Location: ...." + "1" = "Location....1"`

If every time they choose "go north" it's supposed to increase the location variable, then you should have a location variable of type `int`. So add:

```
int loc = 0;
```

To your initialization section, and replace your `player = player + 1;` line with the two lines

```
loc++;
player = locations[loc];
```

Comment: I would do it like that but, since it's a text based adventure game where going north will be adding 1 to the array. I want to be able to type "go north" and it will just add 1 to my location e.g starting at locations[0] > go north > locations[1] > go north locations[2]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the variable "player" should be an int. Set it to 0 at the start. When you want to print the players current location, do:

System.out.println(locations[player]);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define variable `player` as a `int`:

```
 int player =0;
```

then print `location[player]`